# Backing Up Email

Tags: email, backup

What's a good way to backup old emails?  In my case, I own a domain name that forwards all email to a Gmail account.  I'm afraid that Gmail will one day go away, start charging, or lose my emails.  It'd be nice to have the ability to search the emails that have been archived.

Thanks

Comment: Seems more suited for superuser.com?

Comment: Or maybe at the sistersite serverfault.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) to periodically download the email by POP to a set of folders on my backup drive.  GMail can be configured such that it doesn't delete or archive emails when they're downloaded, so it has no effect on the web interface.

Comment: back them up periodically to a dvd - your drive will most likely fail before gmail goes away

Comment: Very nice.  It looks like getmail has IMAP too.

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve all your e-mail to your machine through IMAP/POP3 and backup locally using your mailing agent (Thunderbird, Outlook...)

Comment: I use Gmail, and back up locally into to Thunderbird using IMAP. It works very well. If you're using Thunderbird 3 on Vista, you even get fully-indexed offline searching of your emails via Windows Search.

Comment: Just be careful as Thunderbird Syncs as oppose to Incremental, caught me out when I realised id deleted emails off server and Thunderbird synced these deletions doh! I use GeeBak now on starbanana.com (im nowt todo with them, it just took ages to find a good app to do it)

Answer (score 1):

There's a really good guide at Lifehacker: http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2011/02/gmail-glitch-wipes-out-archives-from-150000-accounts-so-back-yours-up-already/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit paranoid, because gmail is used by a lot of companies worldwide (it's a feature of gmail). If you have a domain, gmail can handle all the mails for it. It's very unlikely that gmail stops its activity in the next decade.

Anyway, it's always a good idea to store data in (at least) 2 different locations. In the case of gmail, the simplest way to "backup" existing mails is to use an IMAP client which will replicate everything that's currently on the server (mails, folders, and a lot of informations), without deleting anything on the server.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using Google Hosted email that provides emails hosting for our company. All our mails are retrieved through to our local computer through IMAP/POP3 with Outlook and backed up locally to DVD.

If you are able to download your emails, then you should consider backing them up to DVDs or other media.